# If statement does not narrow down a union type within another type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
type Foo = { type: 'a' | 'b' }
type Bar = { type: 'a' } | { type: 'b' }

function test(x: { type: 'a' }) {}

function foo(x: Foo) {
  if (x.type === 'a') {
    test(x) // Error
  }
}
function bar(x: Bar) {
  if (x.type === 'a') {
    test(x) // OK
  }
}
```

One would expect types `Foo` and `Bar` to be equivalent, but one results in an error while the other doesn't. Why is this happening?

Comment: `Bar` is a discriminated union with `type` as its discriminant, so checking `type` narrows it.  But `Foo` is not a union at all, let alone a discriminated one. Checking `type` narrows `type` but not the parent object... which is considered a missing feature requested at [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384). See linked q/a for more information.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it only works for discriminated unions - whenever I relied on it before it just worked and I thought it was a general rule.